# How can I get icon from Google icons by code point?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want use a google fonts icon. I have Code point (e88e, info icon). But i cannot get right icon. How can i get right icon from google icons by Code point? Thanks.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIzy6.png]

i used this code but returned wrong icon:

```
Icon icn = const Icon(IconData(0xe88e, fontFamily: 'Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz'), size: 20.0, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 183, 6));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the same icon in Material. For example:

```
`Icon(Icons.info)`
```

The more complicated way to use a custom font is to:

- download it and [add it as a font to your assets](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts)
- use the `fontFamily` option on `IconData`: `Icon(IconData(0xe88e, fontFamily: 'abc'))` (replace abc with the name of your font asset)